# Java webapp to browse and access local file system

Tags: war

This is not really a programming question, except that the answer may be that I need to program it myself. We have a JBoss deployment, and we want to be able to access the filesystem of the server as the running jboss user with the web browser. Is there an off the shelf Java webapp (.war) that will allow this? I know of the security issues, this is an internal server.

Comment: perhaps someone at superuser has a good idea ?